# SSMS - Trying to Bulk insert into a table but decimal field sometimes contains NA

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have tried to create a new table where the column is just varchar(100), but it gives the same conversion error. Most of the column consists of decimal numbers, but instead of putting null or leaving blank when no decimal found the company put NA for NULL values. 
The file will not bulk insert since sometimes there are a significant amount of NA's in the decimal column.
Not sure how to get around the problem. My Bulk Insert (again, i have tried to use varchar(100) for the field and decimal (18,2) but get the same data conversion error

```
Bulk Insert MyExistingTable
From '\\myfile.TXT'
With (   
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
  BATCHSIZE = 10000
  )
```

Comment: Bulk insert into a temp table that is all strings, then move them to your destination using a query that does `NULLIF(decimalcolumn, 'NA')`

Comment: @CaiusJard Would you be able to supply a link in how to transfer the data from my temp table in ssms to my main table? I have not found any examples that work with SSMS 2016 version with data conversions. I found some older type code but the syntax was outdated and was not sure how to translate to current. I can upload some of the code if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've succeeded in loading, for example, a 2 column csv (one column is text, the other is a decimal number but sometimes literal text 'NA' instead of null/empty) you can move data like this:

```
INSERT INTO main(maintextcol, maindeccol)
SELECT temptextcol, NULLIF(tempdeccol, 'NA') from tmp
```

The conversion from text to decimal is implicit. If you have more columns, add them to the query (I made it 2 to keep life simple)

If you want to avoid duplicates in your main table because some data in tmp is already in main:

```
INSERT INTO main(maintextcol, maindeccol)
SELECT t.temptextcol, NULLIF(t.tempdeccol, 'NA') 
FROM 
  tmp t
  LEFT JOIN 
  main m
  ON m.maintextcol = t.temptextcol -- the xxxtextcol columns define the ID in each table
WHERE
  m.maintextcol is null
```

The left join will create nulls in maintextcol if there is no match so this is one of the rows we want to insert. The where clause finds rows like this

Demo of the simple scenario:

> ```
> create table main(a varchar(100), b decimal(18,2
> ))
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table tmp (a varchar(100), b varchar(100))
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tmp values('a', '10.1'),
> ('b', 'NA')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into main 
> select a, NULLIF(b, 'NA') from tmp
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from main
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> a  | b    
> :- | :----
> a  | 10.10
> b  | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a3676d772aa0dbf3c4402e3a463985ae)*

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I do not have enough rep to mark as useful answer, sorry.

Comment: It's no problem; glad it worked out! Helping people to where they need to go, and doing a bit of teaching along the way is the most important bit for me. ps; any up votes you cast now will apply when you do hit whatever points threshold is needed..